# How do you run a for loop through a certain index position within a nested List?

Tags: python, list

I have a list and wanted to know how to access/loop through a list at a certain index position. The reason I want to do this is to only change those elements in those positon. In this example, position 1 is the name of a client and position 2 is the age. I only want to run a condition for the **age** of a client.

```
L = [['Sam', '35'],['John', '45'], ['Steve', '99']]
L = ['Group 1' if '35' in x else 'Group 2' if '45' in x else 'Group 3' for x in L]
```

Result:

```
print(L)
L = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']
```

What I actually want:

```
print(L)
L = [['Sam', 'Group 1'],['John', 'Group 2'], ['Steve', 'Group 3']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
  L = [['Sam', '35'],['John', '45'], ['Steve', '99']]
  L = [[x[0],'Group 1'] if '35' in x else [x[0],'Group 2'] if '45' in x else [x[0],'Group 3'] for x in L]
  print(L)
```

Output:

```
[['Sam', 'Group 1'],['John', 'Group 2'], ['Steve', 'Group 3']]
```

Comment: I see, so you just repeat x[0]. Sorry it seems so simple now!

Comment: Yeah, no worries, it's just a way. Btw it's better to use dictionaries if maybe there are more conditions, as @ScootCork's answer says.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
L = [[i[0], 'Group 1' if i[1] in '35' else 'Group 2' if '45' in i[1] else 'Group 3'] for i in L]
```

Output

```
[['Sam', 'Group 1'], ['John', 'Group 2'], ['Steve', 'Group 3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the first element back in your generated elements:

```
L = [[x[0], 'Group 1' if '35' in x else 'Group 2' if '45' in x else 'Group 3'] for x in L]
```

This would give you the wanted output

Answer (score 1):

Although valid answers have been posted, often when you are writing multiple if statements it could be worth using a dictionary as a lookup. This can more easily be extended with new groups.

```
group_lookup = {'35': 'Group 1', '45': 'Group 2', '99': 'Group 3'}

L = [[x[0], group_lookup[x[1]]] for x in L]

print(L)
```